# How to subset bigger dataframe into smaller dataframes in order to write them as .csvs?

Tags: r

Im trying to create a function which basically splits a data.frame into several smaller dataframes:

```
  split_save <- function(df){

    dataframes <- vector("list",length(df))

    dates <- unique(df$date)

    for (i in 1:length(dates)){ 
    dataframes[[i]] <- df[df$date==dates[i],]
    }

    for(i in 1:length(dataframes)){
      write.csv(dataframes[[i]], paste0(i,".csv"))
    }

  }
```

My problem is that I cant figure out how to split the bigger data.frame into smaller data frames where the split points are based on weeks and write the corresponding week with its name as the smaller data.frame:

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2016-01-04'),as.Date('2018-01-
 12'), by = 1),
       some_data = length(t))


date    some_data

2016-01-04  2
2016-01-05  2
2016-01-06  2
2016-01-07  2
2016-01-08  2
2016-01-09  2
2016-01-10  2
2016-01-11  2
2016-01-12  2
2016-01-13  2
2016-01-14  2
2016-01-15  2
2016-01-16  2
2016-01-17  2
```

Desired output after writing .csv into some dir:

data_for_week1.csv

```
date    some_data

2016-01-04  2
2016-01-05  2
2016-01-06  2
2016-01-07  2
2016-01-08  2
2016-01-09  2
2016-01-10  2
```

data_for_week2.csv

```
   date some_data

   2016-01-11   2
   2016-01-12   2
   2016-01-13   2
   2016-01-14   2
   2016-01-15   2
   2016-01-16   2
   2016-01-17   2
```

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: The function to split a data.frame into smaller parts is called `split`. You just need to compute the `year-week` to use in the split.

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer...

Here's how you can split your data by year-week combinations:

```
dfsplit <- split(df, format(df$date, "%Y-%W"))
```

Then you can loop over the names of the resulting list and write each table to a csv-file:

```
lapply(names(dfsplit), function(x) 
       write.csv(dfsplit[[x]], paste0("dir/data_for_week_", x, ".csv")))
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion: `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
 
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection `

Comment: @Mamba you obviously have to adjust the "dir/data_for_week_" part of my answer to an existing directory